# Split a 512 bit numbers into 16 words of 32 bits using HDL

Tags: programming, hdl

How to split a 512 bit binary number into 32 words of 16 bits using HDL?

Comment: Use alias declarations in VHDL.

Comment: Which HDL? The most common are Verilog HDL and VHDL.

Comment: Verilog HDL sir,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input_word[511 downto 0];

zeroth_output = input_word[15 downto 0];
first_output = input_word[31 downto 16];
...
thirty_first_output = input_word[511 downto 496];